# Xen 4.1 host (dom0) with blktap disks ("tap:aio:") not connecting

Tags: linux, xen, block-device, dom0

Problem using blktap with xen-4.1 running Ubuntu Precise stock kernel with dom0 xen-4.1.

I get:

```
[    5.580106] XENBUS: Waiting for devices to initialise: 295s...290s.
...
[  300.580288] XENBUS: Timeout connecting to device: device/vbd/51713 (local state 3, remote state 1)
```

And some syslog lines:

```
May 17 13:07:30 localhost logger: /etc/xen/scripts/blktap: add XENBUS_PATH=backend/tap/10/51713
May 17 13:07:31 localhost logger: /etc/xen/scripts/blktap: Writing backend/tap/10/51713/hotplug-status connected to xenstore.
```

with tap:aio: disk lines. file:/ works.

```
disk = [
    'tap:aio:/data/root.img,xvda1,w',
]
```

Problem exists with lucid and precises domU kernels and both guests work in Ubuntu hardy dom0 Host 64bit 2.6.24-28-xen xen-3.3

```
 3.2.0-24-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 25 08:43:22 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As with all things problematic. Asking for help usually solves it. Even when no-one answers the question.

So the answers two fold. Apparently installing xen* stuff is not enough in Ubuntu.
Blktap and stuff is separately packages and tapdisk userspace programs and blktap module is needed.

Install `blktap-utils` and dependencies...
You'll get `tapdisk` and with dkms package the kernel module `blktap`.

That was not enough.
Apparently Blktap got changed to blktap2 at some point between Ubuntu Hardy and Precise XEN versions (xen-3.3 -> xen-4.1).
So the disks are included with 'tap2:tapdisk:aio:' not 'tap:aio:'

```
# Use this to convert existing files
perl -i.backup -pe 's/tap:aio:/tap2:tapdisk:aio:/g' *.cfg
```

See [Xen blktap2](http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Blktap2) for tap2 disk options.

---

If you're still having problems with blktap, these next commands might help to diagnose what is missing.

```
ls /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/updates/dkms/blktap.ko && echo run: modprobe blktap || echo Missing module 
ls /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r ) || echo MISSING kernel headers
ls /usr/src/blktap-2* || echo MISSING blktap-dkms
ls /var/lib/dkms/blktap/kernel-$(uname -r)* || echo dkms compilation failed
```

And to activate compile manually for all dkms modules:

```
sudo dkms autoinstall -k $(uname -r)
```

Comment: We should document this on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/XenProposed

Comment: @Manwe i also have similar problem,in my case dom0 and domu are ubuntu 12.04,i tried as mentioned in ur post,but for me its still showing (55808 blktap kernel module not installed) i have installed blktap-dkms blktap-utils in dom0 but still its not working.this is the output of kernel module
xen_netback,xen_blkback      
Can u please help me on this.

Comment: Do you have kernel headers and dkms packages installed? `blktap-dkms dkms linux-headers-generic, linux-headers-3.2.0-31-generic linux-headers-3.2.0-31-generic` and also compile environment for the dkms to work. (kernel version are the latest I've compiled the module with)

Comment: Hey @Manwe i installed blktap and dkms using apt-get and using 3.2.0-23-generic kernel.GCC and other simmilar packages got installed as a dependency when i installed dkms.What am i missing.Can u please guide me.

Comment: @KevinParker I've added some diagnose code to the answer, try those. I would guess that you don't have headers installed for your kernel (nothing here brings them as a dependency) or you have to `modprobe blktap`

Comment: i think "modeprobe blktap" was the step i missed...Thanks alot @Manwe...Finally i got it working.... now i can see blackback running as a process...  :)